# Are Poisson distributions with low mean heavy-tailed?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

It is very apparent to me how using the normal distribution to estimate the probability of large, Poisson-distributed events may lead to significant underestimates of the probability of these events, especially when the mean event rate is low. This matches my intuition of a distribution with a heavy-tail. However, I fail to see how Poisson distributions verify the definition of a [heavy-tailed distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-tailed_distribution). Are Poisson distributions heavy tailed? If not, how does one define the slow probability decay of Poisson distributions with low mean?

Comment: I think it is *not* heavy tailed in the sense of the definition although I'd have to think more about it before I dare type this as answer rather than comment. As you say yourself, the intuition of poissons decaying slowly come from comparing to a normal rather than exponential distribution - I guess one could make a more precise statement about the slow decay by making a more precise comparison tot the normal distribution, although this comparison may not have its own name in the way that the comparison to the exponential has

Comment: With regard to being slower than normal not having its own name: I found this sentence on the Wikipedia page you link to:  "(Occasionally, heavy-tailed is used for any distribution that has heavier tails than the normal distribution.)" So one thing you can do is show it fits this 'occasionally used' definition of heavy tailed but not the other, more standard (?) one, and have a fairly precise statement about how heavy-but-not-too-heavy tailed it is

Comment: Thank you @Vincent for your input!

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/582064/are-poisson-distributions-with-low-mean-heavy-tailed